# How to use Access Token to request JSON from TWITTER API

Tags: swift, api, twitter-oauth, alamofire

I want to build a Twitter client. I have successfully retrieved the access token and secret through the OAuthSwift framework but I have no idea how to use the tokens to make a request to Twitter to retrieve something like a user's timeline in JSON.

How would I use something like Alamofire to send the credentials and get the JSON data? I'm new to working with APIs and Oauth, so I'm pretty confused on the process.

Any insight would be extremely valuable. Will check solved! Thank you